Simplifying equation to a simplistic linear form!
Is there a way to write this equation
$$X + a * b^{\frac{1}{Y}} * Z = c$$
in the linear form
$$a'X + b'Y+ c'Z + d' = 0$$
Where $a,b,c,a',b',c',d'$ are known variables; while $X,Y,Z$ are the unknown variables
Additional info on the context of the problem:

I'm trying to solve $n>100$ nonlinear system of equations in a package/platform that only support solving simplistic linear equations system. I started exploring ways to transform the original equations into a linear form! I reached a dead end after writing it in multiple forms (I shared the above form as the 'shortest' form I managed to write from the original equation)

EDIT/SOLUTION!!
Thanks to @RobPratt useful hint, I managed to re-write the equation in the desired format, but only after assuming new variables X',Y',Z'! would this be the simplest/correct way to transform it?
$$X + a * b^{\frac{1}{Y}} * Z = c$$
$$\ln(a * b^{\frac{1}{Y}} * Z) = \ln(c-X)$$
$$\ln(a) + {\frac{1}{Y}}\ln(b) + \ln(Z) - \ln(c-X) = 0$$
Assumptions:
$$X' = -\ln(c-X), Y' = {\frac{1}{Y}}, Z' = \ln(Z)$$
$$a' = 1, b' = \ln(b), c' = 1, d' = \ln(a)$$
Now we get the linear form for new variables
$$a'X'+b'Y'+c'Z'+d'=0 $$

Hint: Take the logarithm of the second term.

Thank you! I tried this and it looks like I reached the solution!

That is the right idea, but it is simpler to leave $X$ and $c$ unchanged.

I don't think I was able to get the hint this time! How can I leave X and c unchanged?

Sorry, I was oversimplifying.

It took me a while to get the need to express X without c. I would appreciate it if you have any suggestion about it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4952443/simplifying-complex-system-of-equations-n-equation-with-3-unknown-to-linear-sy
