Simplifying complex system of equations (n equation with 3 unknown) to linear system of equations?
I am working on simplifying a system of non-linear equations to linear one by substituting my unknown with new ones. I realized from my previous attempts that I should not express new unknown, e.g., $X'$ as a function of the known of the original equations, otherwise I'll end up with $n$ solution of $X$ in the original equation for each solution for $X'$.
My questions are: Am I correct about this substitution rule? And if so, is there a way to isolate the term to avoid this when substituting?
Below is my example (this is from my previous question, which I rephrased and focused it here in an attempt to be more specific and phrase appropriate question. I hope I managed to communicate better this time)
$$
\begin{aligned}
X + a \cdot b^{\frac{1}{Y}} \cdot Z &= c \\ 
a'X' + b'Y' + c'Z' + d' &= 0, 
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
X' &= -\ln(c-X), & Y' &= \frac{1}{Y}, & Z' &= \ln(Z) & & \\ 
a' &= 1, & b' &= \ln(b), & c' &= 1, & d' & = \ln(a)
\end{aligned}
$$
For this specific example, the issue would be in the term $\ln(c-x)$. Can I express $X'$ without $c$?
